# I want to know the difference between 'Form Created automatically' and 'Existed Form'

Tags: forms, delphi, pascal

Thanks a lot , I want to know the difference between 'Form Created automatically' and 'Existed Form'
in Delphi XE3. (Tools->Options->Forms)

Comment: This entire mess comes about because VB, back in the day, created your forms automatically. And Borland copied that nonsense. Take control of your program and create your objects when you need them.

Comment: Made my comment, on an answer below before I saw yours @DavidHeffernan, mess is right. That damn stupid Form variable in the interface, seen so many newbies fall foul of that while writing poor code. Me included, many moons ago.

Comment: Though the question is trivial it is absolutely clear.

Answer (score 2):

An "auto-created" Form is created automatically for you at program startup.  The IDE inserts a call to `TApplication.CreateForm()` into your project's main source file to accomplish that. The first auto-created Form becomes the `TApplication.MainForm`.

An "available" Form has to be created manually in your own code, which allows you to choose when/how it is created.

Comment: This.  There is no problem with auto-created form for SOME smaller applications.  As applications grow larger, developers usually start creating forms when they need them, but leave a certain small core of forms auto-created, usually the main form and any other form that must exist for the app to work at all.

Comment: @WarrenP, have to disagree, the problem is it's bad habit that makes it easier to develop more, and it was designed to make it easier fro novices, when Delphi competed with VB before .net. Just encourages thinking like the tropical fish example, which we needed like an extra hole in the bottom.

Comment: I have developed some very large applications, and have noticed that a well structured program tolerates forms that are auto-create, and also tolerates failure to auto-create those forms.  There are no problems associate with that.   However, there ARE many problems associated with the general ball of mud structure, tight coupling, and bad cohesion. These have nothing to do with when and how you create and free your forms.

Comment: More about should you use it, than can you use it for me. In my experience which is also considerable, it causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: I would say, an "available" form is a form that has a line in the DPR. It is not something that has real meaning on source level, it is just how the project/designer system finds/organizes its own lists of forms. The true list of all forms requires compilation to find all units that might have form types.

Comment: Yesterday I had a situation where I really needed to remove all global references to a data module so I could strictly control what forms had references to what copy of what data module, and so there are some cases where I know exactly what you mean, Tony, and I agree in principle on all manners of cleanliness and limiting visibility of object references. However, if the forms have no coupling or cross-references (and that's a big IF) then I find it's really no big deal.   Maybe you find your discipline yields big fruits, and so it's great, in your cases.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is the forms,  all get created whether needed or not, and all stay in memory until the application is closed (or they are explicitly destroyed).

My delphi experience suggests that using auto create nearly always leads to poor lifetime management and encourages monolithic code, and in general should be avoided at all costs.